# Getting S3 AccessDenied from C# ElasticBeanstalk application even after adding appropriate bucket policies that use Beanstalk ARN Role to S3 bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

When I try with this bucket policy and all **"Block Public Access"** settings are set to false when I try to `PutObject` into S3, I get an **AccessDenied** Exception.

I've tried numerous permutations and the only permutation that I could get it to work with is a security risk and is when I give wildcard access to the bucket with FULL public access.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

c# Code Snippet:

```
public async Task<IOperationResult<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>> PutFile(
            string bucketName,
            string key,
            Stream inputStream
        )
        {
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                Key = key,
                BucketName = bucketName,
                InputStream = inputStream,
            };

            return await PutObjectAsync(request);
        }
```

Option 1: (Does not work)

```json
# Bucket Policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- I've added AWS Managed policy `"AWSS3FullAccess"` to both roles `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, and `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` to no avail using option 1.

Option 2: (Does not work and this helps protect the bucket)

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-abc0d1efgh"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Option 3: (Does work when all Block Public Access settings are false)

```json
# Bucket Policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've even tried creating specific policy that was attached to any AWS service that may be involved with Elastic Beanstalk

```json
#IAM policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::obfuscated-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  As it stands, I can't see this question as being clear enough. What is the actual problem? Can you please explain what you actually want to do?